# How to give an animation to the image when mouse cursor goes out of the hover area?

Tags: html, css, hover

Using hover with transition ease-in for an image, taking cursor out of the image makes it unpleasant

i've tried :after ,but i'm not sure if thats what i need, if it is , i didn't figure it out (i'm a noob)

this is the code i'm using for hovering

```
.movies img:hover
{
  border: 7px solid white;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 230px;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
}
```

How to add a transition(or something else to smooth it)to make the new border created by the hover disappear with a transtion ?

Comment: i think youre searching for javascript onmouseover and onmouseout

Comment: @godfather but is there a way to do it just by css ?

Comment: i dont think you need to do something like before and after maybe you should style .movies img and then style  .movies img:hover

Comment: @godfather can you give me an example

Comment: style how you want it to be  .movies img{} and then .movies img:hover{}

Comment: add `border:0px solid white` to the non hover state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can smooth it (as you named it) by throwing out

```
transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
```

to your .movies img class, but I'm not sure if that's the solution you're looking for.

Have you got a codepen project for this problem?

Comment: yes it would but i would like to make the new border disappear with a transtion

Comment: setting border property to none in img class (without hover) would help?